# Is there something like a banana plug that will fit in a 30mil or 50mil through hole test point?

Tags: connector, testing, programmer, cost

I am developing a cost sensitive product.  The printed circuit boards need to be programmed and tested.  It seems like a waste of money to put a programming/test connector on the board just to use it only once.

Ideally, I would just put down some through hole test points spaced 50 mils or 100 mils apart, plug something into it, and then remove that device when I am done programming/testing.

Is there some kind of connector that has little spring contacts that fit in a 30 mil or 50 mil through hole test point?  Something like a row of really tiny banana jacks?

Over the years I recall having seen various crimp connector pins with springy contacts that probably would fit into holes on the order of 50 mils or so, but I can't recall what they were called and if I have ever seen them arranged into something like a single row 100 mil connector strip.

I know pogo-pins exist, but those are meant to press against a SMD pad.  I would need to build a fixture for that to work, and I want to avoid that unless I have to.  Something that just plugs into the holes seems like it would be simpler.

Comment: "I know pogo-pins exist, but those are meant to press against a SMD pad." A) They're "test fixture probes" not "Pogo pins". And B) They're meant to press to PCB pads, not just SMD pads.

Comment: You can use offset pins as discussed in this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661598/is-there-a-connector-for-0-1in-pitch-linear-hole-patterns/661606#661606).

Answer (score 2):

One commercial system is called Tag-Connect (https://www.tag-connect.com/). You lay out pads and holes in a specified pattern on your PCB and then a special connector snaps into the holes with pogo-like-pins to connect to the pads.

Note: I have no personal experience with this system.

Answer (score 2):

There are few options:

- [Clips with test fixture probes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MGGCSF1) that you clip on the PCB.
- [Tag connect](https://www.tag-connect.com/) ( that @DoxyLover mentioned)
- [Card edge plugs](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=card_edge_plugs) (my site), but you have to provide traces on the edge of the PCB
- Plain pads with holes on the PCB, into which you insert a pin strip with a cable whose weight forces the pins to lean and make a nice contact with the pads (I believe this is the most common solution)
- The [RedFit SKEDD](https://www.we-online.com/en/components/products/REDFIT_IDC_SKEDD) is great, but not rated for many cycles.

Comment: Plus any number of hacks using pogo pins and clothespegs etc, see e.g. three items currently on https://hackaday.com/blog/?s=programming+pads

Comment: "Plain pads with holes on the PCB, into which you insert a pin strip with a cable whose weight forces the pins to lean and make a nice contact with the pads" a variation of this technique is to stagger the holes, so when you insert a pin strip it presses against the sides of the holes.